# how to set an external hard drive to power down - WIN7

Tags: windows-7, power-management

Wondering how I might set an external hard drive to power down after a certain  period of inactivity on Windows7.

I have read a short tutorial [HERE](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/140592-hard-drive-turn-off-hard-disk-after-idle-never.html), but it seems this option is for ALL hard drives.

Comment: It would be rather under `USB settings`, that setting you linked is for internal drives.

Comment: USB settings where ?

Comment: In power management, but there is enable disable option only.

Comment: What is manufacturer-model of your drive? Usually it is affected by firmware and provided software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via AAM/APM control of the HDD itself (if it supports this feature on a firmware level).
This one of the SMART attributes of the HDD that can be adjusted.
AMP Level
 0 = Disabled
 1 = Minimum power consumption with standby
 2-127 = Intermediate power management levels with standby
 128 = Minimum power consumption without standby
 129-253 = Intermediate power management levels without standby
 254 = Maximum performance and power consumption

Use http://www.hdsentinel.com/ or http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/manual-en/AamApm.html utilities.